# How to obtain an object from a queryset of another object list in django

Tags: python, django, function

i am developing a project with django and i have a little problem.

I am trying to get an array from a querySet of another object. Trying to obtain the "articulo" who has the "carro_det.id_articulo_fk" field, and after send it to the context of my template:

But in the querySet i am getting the error 'int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Articulo''

Specifically in the line: `articulo[i]=Articulo.objects.get(pk=carro_det[i].id_articulo_fk)`

This is from my views.py:

```
def index(request, id_user):
    carro=Carro.objects.get(id_usuario_fk=id_user)
    carro_det=Carro_det.objects.filter(id_articulo_fk=carro.id)

    #HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    for i in range(len(carro_det)):
        articulo[i]=Articulo.objects.get(pk=carro_det[i].id_articulo_fk)
    contexto = {'articulo':articulo,
                'carro_det':carro_det}
    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', contexto)
```

And this is from my models.py, as you can see everything is fine here:

```
class Carro(models.Model):

    total = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    #llaves foraneas
    id_usuario_fk=models.ForeignKey('myuser.Usuario', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_usuario_fk')


    def __str__(self):
        return "id_carro_cliente: " + str(self.id)

class Carro_det(models.Model):
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    precio_venta = models.FloatField(default=0)
    total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    #llaves foraneas
    id_carro_fk=models.ForeignKey('Carro', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_carro_fk')    
    id_articulo_fk=models.ForeignKey('article.Articulo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_articulo_fk')

    def __str__(self):
        return "numero de carro asociado: " + str(self.id_carro_fk.pk)
```

I hope anyone can help me with this, Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these 2 attributes:

```
id_carro_fk=models.ForeignKey('Carro', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_carro_fk')    
id_articulo_fk=models.ForeignKey('article.Articulo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_articulo_fk')
```

are objects not PK's, even though that is how you labeled them. You could do:

```
articulo[i]=Articulo.objects.get(pk=carro_det[i].id_articulo_fk.pk)  # notice the .pk at the end
```

But that isn't the real problem here. It would seem you need to more carefully read the django docs on relationships. It seems like you are accessing all the related `Carro_det` objects to the Carro instance by making those 2 queries, when you could just access the related attribute.

When declaring a `ForeignKey` field in django you are accessing the related object directly, with django creating the id field under the covers. This relationship can be accessed on the other (many) side by accessing:

```
RelatedModel.FKmodel_set
```

or if specified like so:

```
class Carro(Model):
    field = ForeignKey('Model', related_name='related_fields', ...)
```

then:

```
# Carro_det instance
instance.related_fields  # this accesses all carros related to this carro_det
                         # but this is a queryset you can filter down further, it is fetched lazily
```

or in your case:

```
carro_instance.carro_det_set
```

Instead of the way you are doing it...

Answer (score 0):

`carro_det[i].id_articulo_fk` is returning the foreignkey(`Articulo`) instance. Instead, you need to use `id_articulo_fk_id` which is the actual `pk` of the `Articulo` instance.

Use:

```
articulo[i]=Articulo.objects.get(pk=carro_det[i].id_articulo_fk_id)
```